# カスタムキーボードで、画面の縦・横の時の再描画を正しくするには？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

ローテートの時に、うまく動きません。

必要な関数やローテート時に呼び出される関数などあれば、教えていただけないでしょうか？

下記コードでは、縦横切り替え時に、正しく判定されませんが、現在の判定コードです。

iPad用ソフトをiPadでの起動時のみ、正しく動作します。ローテート時は、縦横反対のサイズでキーボードが表示されてしまいます。取得と再描画のタイミングが逆のようです。

iPhoneソフト用のソフトをiPadで強制表示するような周りが黒くなる画面でも、正しく表示されません。

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bunPrint()
    btnTitle1()
    fFastBoot = false
    ...
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bunPrint()
}

func bunPrint(){
    var myNativeBoundSize: CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let myNativeBoundSizeStrW: CGFloat = myNativeBoundSize.width
    let myNativeBoundSizeStrH: CGFloat = myNativeBoundSize.height

    var myWidth = myNativeBoundSize.width
    var myHeight = myNativeBoundSize.height
    print(myWidth)
    print(myHeight)

    // 向きの判定.
    if CGFloat(myNativeBoundSizeStrH) == CGFloat(1024.0) {
        myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(13)
        myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(20)
        print("iPad縦")
    } else if CGFloat(myNativeBoundSizeStrH) == CGFloat(768.0) {
        myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(13)
        myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(11)
        print("iPad横")
    } else {
        myWidth = myNativeBoundSizeStrW / CGFloat(10)
        myHeight = myNativeBoundSizeStrH / CGFloat(10)
        print("Nonエラー")
    }
    ...

    self.button11.frame = CGRectMake(0,3 + fPri, myWidth - CGFloat(2) ,myHeight - CGFloat(6))
    ...
}
```

Comment: これだけだと情報が足りないのでわかりません。この判定コードはどこで呼び出されますか（どこに書いていますか？）？再描画のコードは
どういうもので、どこに書いていますか？

Comment: bunPrint()という関数で、ボタンを表示しています。呼び出しているのは起動時と、上記のviewWillTransitionToSize関数内での2箇所なはずです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: キーボードエクステンションで`viewWillTransitionToSize`って呼ばれますかね？呼ばれてもそこだとタイミングが早すぎると思うので、判定のコードは`viewDidLayoutSubviews`以降に書いてみてください。

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        bunPrint()
    }
としてみましたが、変化なしです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: print(myWidth)とprint(myHeight)で出力される値は期待通りのものですか？

Comment: ローテート時は期待と逆のものが出てきます。myNativeBoundSizeStrHで判定していますが、やはり逆です。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26909/discussion-between-nicora-and-kishikawa-katsumi)しましょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のコードでのみ、正しい動作が確認できました。

```
private func isLandscape() -> Bool {
    // 現時点で Landscape表示が適当かどうかを判断する。
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let screenH = screenSize.height
    let screenW = screenSize.width
    let isLandscapeNow =  !(self.view.frame.size.width ==
        screenW * ((screenW < screenH) ? 1 : 0) +
        screenH * ((screenW > screenH) ? 1 : 0))
    return isLandscapeNow
}
```

この関数を呼んで、縦横の判定を伝えることによって、正しく動作します。