# カスタムキーボードをiPadでiPhone用ソフト使用時に判定の仕方がわからない

Tags: ios, swift

カスタムキーボードで、iPadでiPhone用ソフト使用時を判定するには、どうしたらいいのでしょうか？

```
private func isWidth() -> CGFloat {
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let screenW = screenSize.width
    return screenW
}
```

上記ソースはなぜか「768」という答えしか返ってきません。判定には使えませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 重複候補: [カスタムキーボードで、画面の縦・横の時の再描画を正しくするには？](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14314/%e3%82%ab%e3%82%b9%e3%82%bf%e3%83%a0%e3%82%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%9c%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%a7-%e7%94%bb%e9%9d%a2%e3%81%ae%e7%b8%a6-%e6%a8%aa%e3%81%ae%e6%99%82%e3%81%ae%e5%86%8d%e6%8f%8f%e7%94%bb%e3%82%92%e6%ad%a3%e3%81%97%e3%81%8f%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af)

Comment: 重複していないんです。あちらは縦横判定のみ、こちらは機種判定？あちらの方法だけでは、キーボードが大きく表示されて、はみ出してしまうんです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 聞きたいことはキーボードの大きさを適切に変更したいということだと思いますので、本質的には同じことを聞いてると思いますけど。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単なのは`UIUserInterfaceIdiom`の値をチェックする方法があります。

```
if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Phone {
    // iPhone, iPod touch
} else if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {
    // iPad
}
```

他にもモデル名や機種を判定したり、画面の大きさで判断したりなどでも可能です。

**[Update]**
キーボードエクステンションからですと、上記の方法はiPhoneエミュレーションモードでも常に`.Pad`の値を返します。

キーボードエクステンションからiPhoneエミュレーションモードを判断するのは自分自身のビューのサイズを利用するしかないと思います。

初期状態では`UIInputViewController`に対して`self.view.bounds`のサイズを調べるとiPhoneエミュレーションモードでは`{320, 216}`となっているので、それを使って判定することになります。

ビューのサイズは`viewDidLayoutSubviews()`以降のタイミングでなければ正しい値になっていないので注意してください。

Comment: 上記コードでは、iPadと判定されてしまいます。「iPhone専用ソフトをiPadでの強制表示」時、iPadでない判定を必要としています。画面の大きさなどで判別できるでしょうか？今私のできる判定では、iPad標準時も強制表示状態でも縦1024×横768という回答しか得られません。なにか方法はないでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 確かにキーボードエクステンションからですと、`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`はこの目的には使えませんね。自分自身のビューの大きさから判断する以外にはないと思います。回答に追記しました。

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews()以降ということは、viewDidLayoutSubviews()の中でもいいということですよね？でも、viewDidLayoutSubviews()のなかでも、正しく取得できません。困りました・・・

Comment: UIInputViewControllerのself.view.boundsの値ですよ？UIScreenの値とか違うものを見ていませんか？viewDidLayoutSubviews()は複数回呼ばれるので、最初の１回は幅がゼロだったりします。一度、テンプレートから作り直した素直なプロジェクトで試されると良いと思います。私はその状態で確認を取っています。

Comment: 取得できました。単純に「self.view.bounds.size」だけで取るんですね。ありがとうございました。